# bring Android activity to front from background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, foreground

I have an activity that starts the system browser via Intent. Short before it does that I do a HTTP GET to some other URL. This GET will be answered as soon as the user finishes his task in the browser (logging in using OAuth).

I'd like to be able to close down the browser and / or get my application's activity back to the front.

I do not want to use a WebView because I'd like to avoid the perception that I might be trying to spy on passwords.

Any idea how to solve this? Is it possible at all?

Thanks a bunch!

Daniel

Comment: I think, the default browser implementation traps back key (to go back to previous sites) rather than removing the browser activity from the task stack (assuming you aren't launching browser as a new task via Intent Flags). I'm curious for a solution too...

Comment: This isn't the sort of thing a background process ought to be doing. Rather create a notification the user can respond to at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure OAuth opens up URL which is something like yourapp://success

Next you add a intent filter to handle this custom protocol and address. More details are at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs

Answer (score 1):

Here's what did the trick in my project.

The application manifest is pretty standard:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Here's a code snippet of the background thread that sends the intent to re-show the activity:

```
public class AlarmThread extends Thread {

    private int mSleepTime;

    public AlarmThread(int sleepSeconds) {
        super("AlarmThread");
        mSleepTime = sleepSeconds * 1000;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("thread", "started sleeping for " + mSleepTime + " milliseconds");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mSleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored
        }
        Log.i("thread", "creating intent to bring activity to foreground");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        MainActivity.getContext().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Note that the trick is in the `MainActivity.getContext().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);` part (last line above).

In the MainActivity, I added the `getContext` method:

```
public static Context getContext() {
    return mInstance;
}
```

And the member 'mInstance' is set in the 'onCreate':

```
private static MainActivity mInstance = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Other code....

    mInstance = this;
}
```